# How to minimize the Rayleigh quotient to find the smallest eigenvalue during Lanczos iteration?

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I am interested in finding the largest and smallest eigenvalue of a massive symmetric matrix in order to calculate its condition number. I read that the Lanczos iteration can be used for that purpose. After reading [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) as well as the lecture notes from [UTexas](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Esanghavi/courses/scribed_notes/Lecture_13_and_14_Scribe_Notes.pdf) on Lanczos iteration, I am still unclear how one solves the subproblem of minimizing $\lambda_{min}=\min_{z \in \mathcal{K}} r(z)$, where $r$ is the Rayleigh quotient and $\mathcal{K}$ is the Krylov subspace.

Can someone please walk me through how that subproblem is solved? In particular, does one use gradient descent for that or is there a more efficient way? How can solving that minimization subproblem at $k^{th}$ Lanczos iteration be used for solving at the $(k+1)^{th}$ iteration? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $Q$ is the orthonormal Krylov basis and $T$ is the corresponding tridiagonal matrix. Then $Q^TQ=I$ and $Q^TAQ = T$.

Any vector in Kyrlov subspace can be written $Q c$, where $c$ gives the coefficients for a linear combination of the column of $Q$. Thus,
$$
\min_{x\in\mathcal{K}} \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} 
= \min_{c\in\mathbb{R}^k} \frac{(Qc)^TA(Qc)}{(Qc)^T(Qc)}
= \min_{c\in\mathbb{R}^k} \frac{c^T(Q^TAQ)c}{c^T(Q^TQ)c}
= \min_{c\in\mathbb{R}^k} \frac{c^TTc}{c^Tc}.
$$
But the rightmost expression is simply the smallest eigenvalue of $T$.
The same approach holds for the large eigenvector.

Comment: Thank you very much.